# How to update a C# project with a data source when the SQL database has been modified

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

I have created a database with several tables. Using Visual Studio 2012, I created a DataSource object that connects to those tables and created a DataGrid and some forms using the data from the SQL database.

In the process of development I then made changes to the SQL database. In one case I designated a column as a key in a table I had neglected to choose a key for. Now I want my application and the DataSource object to recognize these SQL changes.

How do I do that?

Comment: can you provide some more information here?  Are you using an ORM to connect to your database?  Are you using ADO?  Better yet, can you paste a small code sample so that we can get an idea?

Comment: In the data sources window I clicked on "Add New Data Source" and entered the name of the sql server and the database and tables. Then an entry in that list titled "MyDataSet" appeared. I dragged the table of interest onto a windows form to create the dataGrid view. In another form I created a combo box with a DataSource set to the Binding Source that was created by the DataSet. So to answer your question whether it is ORM or ADO, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Bill, I believe I understand the problem now.  Yes there is a way through the GUI is Visual Studio to pull the changes from your database into the Dataset you have created.  Here is how you do it.  Open the Data Sources Tab -> Select your DataSet  You can see that mine is called People.

[image]

Now, I have updated my database by adding another column called "Phone" that I want to add to my dataset.  I right click on the dataset and select Configure Data Source With Wizard.

[image]

I will expand the data objects selection and select my new column value.

[image]

Then click finish and my Dataset now has the new column in it.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much! I think I had tried something like that but failed to save the changes.

Comment: Awesome @BillOnesty , glad I could help.  Can you mark the question as answered please?